# Apply ripple effect on click of a relative layout which already has a background XML

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a ripple effect on click of a relative layout which already has a background XML. But how can I do this? If I want to add the ripple effect to the relative layout then I must change the tag in the background XML to `<ripple></ripple>`, but when I do this I lose the corner radius and solid color that I had given for the relative layout.

Below is the code of the relative layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="400dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:background="@drawable/roundedcorners">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is the code in the background XML "roundedcorners"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#000000"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="25dp"/>
</shape>
```

I looked out for posts for the same but did not find one, as the posts had just the information on how to achieve the ripple effect, but not on how to merge and use the ripple effect, scale, or shape tags together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for this lies in the special mask layer of the [RippleDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html). You specify the **mask layer** via the `android:id` value set to `@android:id/mask`.

For the example below, you can set the mask to the same size/shape as the view you’re masking, and then the ripple will only show for that area. Do something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
        <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
           <shape 
              android:shape="rectangle">
              <solid android:color="#000000"/>
               <corners
                 android:radius="25dp"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corners" />
    </ripple>
```

now you can set it as your  `android:background`

Comment: Thank you so much! it helped me a lot!